# Using Bing Maps app to show certain directions

Tags: java, google-maps, bing-maps

I understood that integrating maps can be a pain in Java. So I thought of a way around. Can this be possible that the java app opens the Bing Maps App on the PC show directions to the nearest Utility say hospital!
OR
Open the browser,open G Maps and show the directions.

thank you

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why integrating maps in Java should be particularly hard, but, to answer your question: You can create a hyperlink that launches the Bing Maps website with a particular route pre-calculated using the rtp parameter. e.g. http://www.bing.com/maps/default.aspx?rtp=adr.Norwich,Norfolk~adr.Oxford,%20Oxon~adr.Edinburgh,%20Scotland

More examples at http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/url-parameters-for-the-bing-maps-website/

Alternatively, you can use the Bing REST services to create a static map image (i.e. a JPG or PNG file) highlighting a route or location http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx - presumeably you can embed a map image in your Java application?

Comment: Pain because..google maps has no java api, it has a javascript api, MapQuest also moved to java script.
If you can help integrate those maps it would be great